# "hill climbing, change max number of threads 5" when debugging on my androiddevice in xamarin forms when I load data

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I load data from my DB and when I push buttons to recieve different data I get "hill climbing, change max number of threads 5" in the log, and it makes the app slow when I try to gather the data.

Any idea how to resolve this? Or is this even making the app slower? It sure seems like something is spooky because it takes a few extra seconds when I load data on an android-device compared to an ios.

This is my code:

```
static public async Task<JObject> getContacts ()
{
    var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();
    try {
        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://address.com");
        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

        return jsonResult;

    } catch {

        return null;
    }


}
```

And how I use it:

```
async void createData (object s, EventArgs a)
{
    var getContacts = await parseAPI.getContacts ();

    if (getContacts != null) {
        listview.ItemsSource = null;
        theList = new List <items> ();

        foreach (var items in getContacts["results"]) {
            theList.Add (new items () {
                Name = items ["Name"].ToString (),
                Number = items ["Number"].ToString ()
            }); 
        }
    }
    listview.ItemsSource = theList;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Hill climbing" is a fairly common within the Mono runtime as the adaptative thread pool count is increasing (or decreasing) based upon current depends.

Personally I doubt that a thread count of 5 is causing any problems within your app. Seeing 30, 50, 100+ could/would be a problem as the thrashing of context switching can/will bring an app (and OS) to its knees.

In terms of OS "speed", the `iOS` **simulator** vs. an Android **emulator**  is huge. Instrument and Perf test on actual devices.

The Mono Heuristic thread pool reference:

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/metadata/threadpool-ms.c

```
hill_climbing_change_thread_count (gint16 new_thread_count, ThreadPoolHeuristicStateTransition transition)
{
    ThreadPoolHillClimbing *hc;

    g_assert (threadpool);

    hc = &threadpool->heuristic_hill_climbing;

    mono_trace (G_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, MONO_TRACE_THREADPOOL, "[%p] hill climbing, change max number of threads %d", mono_native_thread_id_get (), new_thread_count);

    hc->last_thread_count = new_thread_count;
    hc->current_sample_interval = rand_next (&hc->random_interval_generator, hc->sample_interval_low, hc->sample_interval_high);
    hc->elapsed_since_last_change = 0;
    hc->completions_since_last_change = 0;
}
```

Comment: getting 30 when i enable all of my functions (i work with beacons). the project is "old". could the problem get fixed if i make a brandnew project and copy the oldcode to that project?

Comment: @medvedo creating a new solution/project would not change anything. That thread count without an instrumentation and profiling context does not mean much. You could have 50 threads in a thread pool and 90+% of them could be in a wait state... if you are having perf issues with your Android app, Xamarin has a Profiler, also you can use the Google's Android Device Monitor, etc...

Comment: it seems like alot of my functions is in wait state yes. as i havea a function that is always looking for beacons, it takes the app 5 seconds to react to some of my click calls that should gather data. what exactly do u do in the profiler + device monitor? I have only used it for screenshots

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html  http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html